# Error: This class should be public [Instantiatable]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I  tried to create a release apk for my application but I get an error

but debug apk is working fine

this the error

Error:Error: This class should be public (yyc.xk.xk.myVideoView) [Instantiatable]

```
package yyc.xk.xk;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.VideoView;

class myVideoView
        extends VideoView
{
    int hh = 0;
    int ww = 0;

    public myVideoView(Context paramContext)
    {
        super(paramContext);
    }

    public myVideoView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet)
    {
        super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
    {
        setMeasuredDimension(this.ww, this.hh);
    }

    public void setSize(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
    {
        this.ww = paramInt1;
        this.hh = paramInt2;
    }

}
```

Comment: "_This class should be public_" Can you explain exactly which part of this is not making sense to you?

Comment: `public class myVideoView extends VideoView ...`

Comment: @csmckelvey I am not a developer that's why could you give me a little help

Comment: @Shivam Verma thanks is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at the code, try adding `public` to `class myVideoView extends VideoView`. As well as setting your class attributes to private and the necessary getters & setters for them (if applicable):

`private int hh = 0;
private int ww = 0;`

This should fix the error.